# My data for spend is listed in thousands while my data in sales is listed in millions. Using R, how can I adjust the values in spend?

Tags: python

My data in spend is listed in thousands and my data in sales is listed in millions. Using R, how can I change the values in my spend column? However, I don't want it to be converted, I just want it to "add zeroes" to make it millions instead of thousands. Example of what I mean:

```
   TV Spend   Radio Spend   Sales
A  230,100    37,800        22,100,000
B  44,500     39,300        10,400,000
C  17,200     45,900        9,300,000
```

Changed to

```
  TV Spend    Radio Spend   Sales
A 230,100,000  37,800,000   22,100,000
B 44,500,000   39,300,000   10,400,000
C 17,200,000   45,900,000   9,300,000
```

My dataframe is saved in `df_ad_spend`. I tried the following code, but it converted it:

```
df_ad_spend['TV'] = df_ad_spend[('TV')]/1e6
```

I was thinking it might be possible to use either the `replace` function:

```
df_ad_spend['TV'] = df_ad_spend['TV'].replace([?], [?])
```

Or something with/similar to `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df_ad_spend['TV'] = pd.to_numeric(df_ad_spend['TV'], errors='coerce')
```

Or an if/else function?

Comment: Are you asking about R or about Python?

Comment: Just multiply or divide by 1000, assuming they're stored as numbers in the dataframe rather than as strings.

Comment: `/1e6` is dividing by 1 million, not 1 thousand. That's too much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.